# htaccess redirect get parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, typo3

I got an old site with links like this

> http://example.com/folder/serve.asp?var=10&var2=55

I need to redirect them to the new typo3 version with links like this

> http://example.com/index.php?id=5&tx_myplugin_plugin[action]=show&tx_myplugin_plugin[controller]=data&tx_myplugin_plugin[var2]=55

I tried editing the .htaccess and adding

> RewriteRule ^folder/serve.asp??var=10&var2=([0-9]+)$
>   index.php?id=5&tx_myplugin_plugin[action]=show&tx_myplugin_plugin[controller]=data&tx_myplugin_plugin[var2]=$1
>   [L,NC]

after the RewriteEngine On

but the `tx_myplugin_plugin[var2]` is always empty .

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out

> RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+folder/serve.asp\?var=10&var2=([^\s&]+) [NC]
>
> RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/index.php?id=5&tx_myplugin_plugin[action]=show&tx_myplugin_plugin[controller]=data&tx_myplugin_plugin[var2]=%1 [R=302,L]